# R: convert JAGS output matrix to array based on column names

Tags: arrays, r, matrix, indices, jags

In R, I have a JAGS model output (made in parallel with `jags.parfit` from the `dclone` package) that is a list of six 2-dimensional matrices (corresponding to six chains each with 3000 reps) with column names equivalent to the indices of an array. The first digit has 3 unique values, the second 2000, the third 4, and the fourth 6.

```
head(colnames(m1[[1]]))
[1] "y.pred[1,1,1,1]" "y.pred[2,1,1,1]" "y.pred[3,1,1,1]" "y.pred[1,2,1,1]" "y.pred[2,2,1,1]" "y.pred[3,2,1,1]"
```

I want to convert this long-form matrix into an array with 5 dimensions which correspond to the 3000 reps as row and the 4 indices from the column names as new columns. This array will have the following dimensions:

```
dim(m1.array)
[1]    3000    3 2000    4    6
```

Is there a relatively straightforward way to do this?

UPDATE

Based on the below suggestion, I was able to convert each matrix to the expected array with the following code:

```
m1.arrayList <- lapply(m1, function(x) array(x, dim = c(3000, 3, 2000, 4, 6)))
```

I was then able to convert the list of 5-dim arrays into a 6-dim array with:

```
m1.array <- simplify2array(m1.arrayList)
```

Comment: I edited the question, but elected not to use `dput` because the output was too lengthy -- I instead added some more details. Hopefully it's easier to understand now.

Comment: If you know the order of the columns for sure, you may use `array()` without depending on the colnames; something like `array(unlist(m1), dim = c(3, 2000, 4, 6, 6))`. But this is dangerous if the order of the columns is not "as expected" by `array()`.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I know in which order the dimensions are applied? For example, are rows first, then columns, and if more dimensions >2 exist, the columns are subdivided?

Comment: `array(data, dim)` fills the array with `data` according to `dim` "with the leftmost subscript moving fastest" (see `?array`). So if the colnames are in leftmost-moving-fastest order (which your example suggests), this should work.

Play around with the following toy example to see how it works: `array(unlist(list(matrix(1:12, 3, 4), matrix(21:32, 3, 4))), dim = c(3, 2, 2, 2))
`.